# How to handle touch events with html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, touch-event

I have created the painting based feature with html5 canvas. When it comes to the desktop it's working as I expected, but the problem only in touch devices. I'm clueless where is the issues are coming from. Can someone help me to fix this one? I'm struggling with past two days.

My code

```
if(windowWidth <= 1024) {
  canvas2.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
      mouse.x = e.pageX;
      mouse.y = e.pageY;
      handlerPos.x = e.pageX;
      handlerPos.y = e.pageY;
  }, false);
} else {
  canvas2.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    mouse.x = e.pageX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY;
    handlerPos.x = e.pageX;
    handlerPos.y = e.pageY;
  }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this

> Unfortunately, all was not well. An issue arose from a conflict with built-in browser gestures. When I moved my finger on the canvas, I wanted the page to stay still so I could draw. However, if my page had horizontal or vertical scrolling (and it did) the page would move along with my finger and making proper drawing impossible. After some frustration, I stumbled upon the solution: preventing scrolling on document.body if the target of a touch event is the canvas.

http://bencentra.com/code/2014/12/05/html5-canvas-touch-events.html

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
   mouse.x = e.pageX;
   mouse.y = e.pageY;
   handlerPos.x = e.pageX;
   handlerPos.y = e.pageY;
}, false);
```

Comment: This solution is not working anymore, because event listeners on document are passive, which means preventDefault() has no effect